# testcafe - 1.9.0 openwindow maximizeWindow is not maximizing the new window

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

How to maximize new window.

Code: await t.openWindow('http://example.com').maximizeWindow();

Issue: thew new window is not maximizing.

Comment: What does it do then?

Comment: the no change in the size. it remains as a popup with half the screen size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this was a bug, and has been resoled in `v1.10.0`. If you upgrade, you should be able to see the window re-size.

https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/5885